# Should I include a work experience from >10 years ago?

Tags: resume, work-experience

I'm currently applying for a job and the job description states that "Practical SQL knowledge would be a plus". I do have a lot practical SQL knowledge, even though I haven't used it in quite a while. In 2010-2013, I was an apprentice as a business software developer in the IT department of a large non-IT company, and this job was mainly about building database applications, so very SQL heavy.

10 years is quite some time, especially in this industry. Does it make sense to include this item on my resume or should I focus on more recent (yet not less relevant) work experience considering that my resume is already quite stuffed?

Comment: If you include it, be prepared to answer questions about it, ideally with something better than "I don't remember, but it will come back to me".

Comment: Germany is special, here companies have a black curtain in their eye for things 5 years ago.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should include it, it's directly relevant.

SQL hasn't changed that much in 10 years either. Practical experience like yours just needs a brush up to be up and productive.

Comment: SQL is one thing I grudgingly have to concede that they got really right all that time ago! Never goes out of style, no SQL 99 or whatever. It just works.

Comment: @HappyIdiot SQL, the one thing that caused more security issues than probably anything else "they got really right"? Explicit parameterization is a 'hack' on top of SQL to make it safe, not a core part of SQL. Having applications write 'code' was a bad idea from start to finish. They got SQL right as a thing for humans to write, but it was a big mistake to use it as the 'API' for databases. It not going 'out of style' is more a reflection on human nature than anything else. (Easy to start with, but increasingly problematic as complexity increases). (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) and not even talking about the mistake that joins were. Specifically how the output is forced into a single table... which once again makes sense for direct human consumption on a display, but makes absolutely no sense at all when an application consumes the output. </rant> (Didn't realize I was so passionate about  that... especially as I have not found a single query solution that feels 'close to perfect' having tried and used many)

Comment: @DavidMulder the security issues are not in SQL per se, but in not using prepared statements. The security issues aren't relevant to the question or the answer, either. (I don't think HappyIdiot's comment is completely correct either, but it's off-topic as well so nothing of this all belongs here.)

Comment: @DavidMulder I literally have no idea what you are talking about. How is explicit parameterization a hack? What would you propose?

Comment: @DavidMulder oh, yes, that's part of why I said 'grudgingly'. SQL is the worst method, except for all the others. If we'd asked people what they *wanted*, they would have said "better computer scientists." Cars are not dangerous overall, 99% of the accidents are caused by the nut that holds the steering wheel. Soon steering wheels will be gone and we can all sleep easy, like Homer Simpson coming home from work.

Comment: @DavidMulder SQL is a language to access a data bank. There is no security issue there, the people that write SQL statements are meant to access the data bank. Now if you build say a website where people enter things and these things are used to access a data bank, then you easily run into security issues but that is not an SQL problem. That is a problem of how user input is transferred to the data bank and that code is not SQL.

Comment: @HappyIdiot "no SQL 99 or whatever". Not sure how I should break that to you, but there's a SQL99. Also a SQL 2003 and many more. There's even quite a few very useful things in the later standards (e.g. Merge in 2003/8) that one should definitely know.

Comment: @quarague There absolutely is an inherent security problem in SQL in itself and that is the mixing of code and data. There is a reason that virtually nobody writes SQL statements by hand but uses some abstraction to avoid that problem. There being no clear separation is not set in stone and you can absolutely have a standard that clearly separates those two which would avoid those potential security issues.

Comment: @Voo "*Good, that's the spirit!*" SQL was designed as a *query* language, but people just don't know where to stop. Like web pages where they think that the few pixels needed for a scroll bar can be sacrificed on the altar of profit, and it has to look like a glossy magazine page on every device. (it is time for a few colorful metaphors, really!)

Comment: Well, getting stuff right to be useful for decades to come isn't easy and people have built band aids and coffins around the "sins" of our predecessors because what's even harder is to rewrite all that stuff every couple of decades when the experts of old aren't around us anymore and gone is the knowledge with them. But I suppose, all this is slightly off-topic for this :)

Comment: @Voo I have the impression we work in very different settings regarding SQL. I do write SQL statements by hand at work everyday and so does everyone else in my company who accesses the data bank. The customers request an abstract analysis of the data but they never go anywhere near the actual raw data. I'm also unsure how you want to complety separate SQL and data in something like 'SELECT ... WHERE column_A='abc' .

Comment: @quarague Do you? I personally use one of the various abstractions such as prepared statements that allow me to separate code from data which not only improves performance greatly but also eliminates security risks. And before we go there, no prepared statements are not SQL (even if that's very confusing for younger programmers who get taught from the beginning to use them, exactly because SQL itself is so problematic) - if you want to convince me otherwise you'll have to show me the part of the specification that specifies them.

Comment: @voo In my daily work I write SELECT statements and I have to think about which data is in which table, hwo to join them together, group the data, etc. The end goal is usually a presentation that explains what the data 'means' so there are usually several iterations of preparing SQL statements to actually get what I need.

Comment: @quarague Most companies use BI software for that, but to be fair, you *are* using SQL how it was 'intended to be used' 40-50 years ago when it was invented. Most of us are just really surprised to hear that anybody still uses it like that in this day and age... I would bet that 99% of SQL usage is now generated by other code, but clearly there is still a 1% of legacy use to be found.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the game, but consider that SQL, the language that is often supported as being great, wasn't even loved by E. F. Codd, the "creator" of the relational database.  IBM slapped it in because Codd took forever for creating the "correct language" to query the database.  SQL is only awesome today due to everyone having learned it with all of its warts.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_theorem clearly details that counting results, NULL values, three-valued logic (true, false, null), and multiset semantics (A, A, B) were never part of Codd's Relational Calculus.

Comment: @DavidMulder I think it is important to understand the data structure and not just let a tool whip stuff up. So even if the tool helps, I'd still say that knowing the joins and so on is necessary or else you can end up with weird, inefficient and incomprehensible things. I wish it was mandatory that people should have to understand electricity, plumbing, radio, how cars work, and all the other things that we are completely dependent on. No one should feel safe relying on black boxes, and companies should see it as an existential risk. But enough about me...